# magento2 how to remove Advanced Pricing link on Add Product page

Tags: magento2

In magento 2 I want to  remove Advanced Pricing link on Add/Edit Product page

If any body have an idea please reply.

Comment: why u want to remove the advance pricing link which is a major functionality>??

Comment: Because i don't want this...